# How to replace files according to environment in Angular, before build?

Tags: angular, webpack

I have an Angular app with production and development environments.
The app connects to firebase, with a configuration file called `GoogleService-Info.plist` that is downloaded from firebase, and has different file content for each environment. (i.e. the content of `GoogleService-Info.plist` for production is different from the content for development).

So far, if I had to build for development, I would use the GoogleService-Info.plist file downloaded with development config. When I had to build for production, I would download GoogleService-Info.plist from firebase with production configuration, and replace the file in my Angular app and run `ng build -c=production` to build for production.

GoogleService-Info.plist is used by an external plugin that looks for it in a specific folder, and I can't write the following logic in my angular app to dynamically determine which file to use:

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

const configFilePath_prod = 'path/to/file/GoogleService-Info-prod.plist';
const configFilePath_dev = 'path/to/file/GoogleService-Info-dev.plist';

const configFilePath = environment.production
    ? configPath_prod
    : configPath_dev;
```

I tried to use the file replacement array in the `angular.json`:

```
"production": {
    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": ["src/assets/scss/web"]
    },
    "fileReplacements": [
        {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
    ],
    ...
```

but it can only replace .json and .js and .ts files, so I can't use it to replace .plist files.

My question is: how can I write a loadign script/what tool can I use that allows me to "replace" the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file depending on the environment, before the angular build takes place?

Answer (score 1):

Does your external plugin take command line parameters?

A common practise is to use prefixed npm scripts:

```json
// package.json
{

  "scripts": {
     "build:dev": "npx external-plugin --path /your-path-for-dev && ng build --configuration=dev",
     "build:prod": "npx external-plugin --path /your-path-for-prod && ng build --prod"
  }
}
```

#### Edit

Since your file contains text you an apply same technique as described before and use some basic bash output redirection to update the file's contents before building or starting the development server:

Create all flavors of your plist file and rename them as you find suitable, for instance:  `googleinfo.prod.plist, googleinfo.dev.plist ...`

Then in your npm scripts you can do:

```json
// package.json
{

  "scripts": {
     "build:dev": "cat googleinfo.dev.plist > path/to/googleinfo.plist && ng build --configuration=dev",
     "build:prod": "cat googleinfo.prod.plist > path/to/googleinfo.plist && ng build --prod"
  }
}
```

And apply symmetrical fixes for dev-server

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: What's the content inside that .plist file? (Binary, text...?)

Comment: It's text. used by iOS app (building an ionic iOS app).

Comment: I've added another workaround to your problem

Comment: That's really smart. Thanks a lot. To solve this problem I went on to learn more about webpack, and I think it has an automated solution. I'll update here when I finish my research.

Comment: 'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, i am facing this error on windows

Comment: You'll have to install  `mingw`, `git-bash` or `wsl` as `cat` is a UNIX utility that doesnt belong to CMD-DOS. Not sure which one is the counterpart for cat in MS-DOS